# Whether or not to include external DLLs in C# project

Tags: c#, dll, project, external

Our project has a lot of external DLLs, most but not all of which are 3rd party DLLs.

Currently we do not have these DLLs included in our project.  They are included in SVN and given a path to our build output directory.  So, after building our project the neccessary files are there, because of SVN, but the project itself has no knowledge of them.

My feeling is that we should have a folder under the root of our project named something like Dependancies or ThirdParty with all of the DLLs included there and set their build event to copy to the output directory.  They would exist in SVN as well, but in the same structure as the project, not in the build output directory.

The project itself only references one of these DLLs called CommunicationProc.DLL.  The CommunicationProc.DLL then references all of the other DLLs.  We have numerous DLLs to support different types of radio.  So not all DLLs will be used, but any one of them may be used depending on the radio type.

As to whether or not the DLLs should be included in the project we have differing opinions internally, some of the team beleives they should only be in SVN and not part of the project itself.

Of note is that this are not .NET DLLs, most are old C DLLs.

What is the accepted practice?  Can someone please provide me with a compelling arguement one way or the other as to whether to include them in the project or just SVN?

Comment: By include in the project, do you mean in a folder in the project. Or as part of the repo?

Comment: How are you building your project without referencing required DLLs?  One benefit of referencing them in VS is auto-complete.  You can reference DLLs in folders outside of your projects using relative paths.

Comment: this is a shot in the dark - isn't there a tool to combine assemblies? ilmerge maybe?

Comment: Honestly neither answer is more correct or better. The end result is the same: The DLLs exist both where they need to be to load and exist in source control. Flip a coin or have a wrestling match to determine the winner.

Comment: @Tergiver; I disagree. Using a project and referencing the assemblies is by far better than manually copying assemblies into the 'BuildOut' folder.

Comment: @AMissico: According to the question, there is no manual copying, an SVN checkout produces the files. Anyhow, it's a subjective question and, like all subjective questions, is going to elicit both opinions.

Comment: @Tergiver; I am disagreeing with your comment. Both answers are not the same, and suggesting a coin flip to make a decision is shows lack of experience. If you want your source code and external assemblies to be in-synch and always compile, then you put your external assemblies into your Visual Studio project and you reference your projects to this assemblies. MSBuild will take care of the rest. If you do not do this, then it is easy to get these out-of-sync with each other. This is a fact. How you do this, is a matter of opinion. (Note, external assemblies in the GAC is a different issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its better to have them in a folder on source control and then copy them over to the debug folder on build event. This way you can manage their versions. If a newer version of some dll comes then you can replace the old one and put some comments with check in. Also if you are working in a team, then instead of copying files from debug folder to each team member, you can let each team member to use the same set of dlls from source control. If you are developing some control and want your customers to use that control then its easier for you to  have a set of dependent dlls some where so that you can give those to your customer along with your .Net dlls. 
I had the same issue with some un-managed dlls and ended up putting them in a folder so that all the team members have the same version of the dlls. Hope this helps.

Comment: We do currently have them under source control.  We have a BuildOut directory that we are building to.  In the BuildOut\ThirdParty directory we have all of these DLLs and this is where source control has them.  When you check out the project from source control you get the DLLs.  If a DLL is updated the next time you do an SVN Update you will get the new version.  This is what we have and appears to be what you are suggesting.  What I am trying to determine though is whether or not it should be our Visual Studio solution as well.

Comment: @WPFNewbie, sorry for not being clear, That is what I meant. Have it as a folder under your Visual Studio solution in your project. This way it will be more simple.

Answer (score 1):

I include a project that has no code but contains a folder where all the external assemblies and their dependencies are kepts. For each file set the Build Action to None and Copy to Output as Do Not Copyp. The project then references the binaries from this location. In your other projects, reference this special project. When you build, because the special project is referenced and it references all the needed dependencies, the binaries are copied as needed.

If you do not want a special project, still create the folder in your main project, added the assemblies, set their properties, then reference the assemblies as needed.

This gives you complete control over the versions and output, and more importantly, it is simple.